# InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (13 Permission denied)

Tags: python, html, mysql, apache, cgi

I'm trying to host an application on apache2 server using python CGI framework. The program works fine when compiled and there is no error.
When I try it on the web browser I get the error.

```
InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (13 Permission denied)
```

I have tried installing mysql-connector-python and checked if I'm missing anything. Everything seems to be fine. Below is the code with the error in detail.

```
def connectdb():
    mydb = mx.connect(host='localhost',user='******',passwd='********',database='searchdb')
    cur=mydb.cursor()
    return mydb,cur
```

Error when trying to access the program.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/html/ftest.py", line 116, in <module>
  mydb,cur=connectdb()
File "/var/www/html/ftest.py", line 55, in connectdb
mx.connect(host='localhost',user='*****',passwd='********',database='searchdb')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 98, in connect
  return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 118, in __init__
  self.connect(**kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 382, in connect
  self._open_connection()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 345, in _open_connection
  self._socket_open_connection()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 386, in _open_connection
  errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (13 Permission denied)
```

This is the error that I'm facing. Anyone familiar with this issue, Please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some things to check, assuming this is a Linux machine:

- Make sure you can connect locally using the same user name and password.
  `mysql -u [youruser] -p`
- If SELinux is running, make sure the "httpd_can_network_connect_db" boolean is set to on.  Check with `sudo getsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db`.  If it comes back as "off," set it to "on" with `sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db on`.  (Make sure to include the -P, or it will revert back to the original value if the system restarts.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mike. This fixed the issue.

Comment: @Mike please delete your anser from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61845045/error-tuple-object-is-not-callable-even-when-my-syntax-is-correct     Thanks