# Permission error when trying to connect to MySQL DB using CGI Script

Tags: python, html, mysql, cgi

Little background, I'm running a small CGI script with Python that takes form value and inserts it into MySQL Database.  I run my own Apache (httpd) server with MySQL.  Here is my connection argument:

```
import mysql
import mysql.connector
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='xxxx', password='xxxx', host='localhost', port='3306', database='DID_MASTER')

if conn:
    print("connected successfully")
else:
    print("connection not established")
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/getData.py", line 11, in <module>
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='xxxx', password='xxxx', host='localhost', database='DID_MASTER')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 287, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 137, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1108, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 533, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 576, in open_connection
    ) from err
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (13 Permission denied)
[Fri Dec 09 08:47:36.304380 2022] [core:error] [pid 4890:tid 139695883282176] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 172.16.19.65:59261] AH00574: ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed, referer: http://10.143.110.70/user_add.html
[root@localhost html]#
```

Not sure how this is permission issue because I've opened up the firewall for SQL connection and I have no issues accessing the DB from the outside.

Comment: "Permission Denied" means "your credentials are wrong". Note that if you had firewall issues, you wouldn't get that, you'd get something like "connection refused". This means you can connect but you're being turned away.

Comment: Its the same credentials I use to connect remotely and the ones that I've set up.  Is the 'localhost' wrong?  I've also used the IP in the arguments but still getting same message.

Comment: Remote and local credentials are often different, so do check you've set them correctly for both use cases.

Comment: Is there a way to verify that?  I don't recall setting 2 set of credentials.

Comment: Often you'll see credentials for host `localhost` and host `%` (remote) separately.

Comment: I just tested connection on the server itself with my root credentials and it connected fine.

Comment: MySQL isn't lying here. Either you've entered them wrong in Python, or they're not set up correctly. You need to determine which case is true. Consider connecting via MySQL socket if you can, that is often a lot closer to the `localhost` experience.

Comment: [root@localhost html]# mysql -u root -h localhost -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 15
Server version: 8.0.28 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Comment: Note that `mysql` automatically converts `localhost` to the UNIX socket connection which uses *different credentials*. It's annoying but true. Try with 127.0.0.1 and you might see different results. Within MySQL configuration "localhost" means "local UNIX socket connection".

Comment: Tested with 127.0.0.1 and still same thing.

Comment: Found the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710007/interfaceerror-2003-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-localhost3306-13-perm